# Access EC2 resources from AWS Lambda JS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I'm writing a function which needs to make some requests to EC2 to create and delete snapshots. However there is currently no feature in Lambda to directly making requests with EC2 resources. I'm attempting to use [Class: AWS.TemporaryCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/TemporaryCredentials.html) but there is a notice that writes:

> Note: In order to create temporary credentials, you first need to have
>   "master" credentials configured in AWS.Config.credentials. These
>   master credentials are necessary to retrieve the temporary
>   credentials, as well as refresh the credentials when they expire.

So I'm not sure how to store the credentials since this Lambda is only a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for your Lambda function to make EC2 requests, you have to create an IAM role that has the necessary permissions and then associate that role with your IAM function.  The AWS Lambda `CreateFunction` API request has a required parameter called `Role` which would be the ARN of the new role you have created.  In this way, each time your Lambda function is run Lambda will create temporary AWS credentials for it to use that have the permissions defined in the role.